# Regex attribute not throwing error when testing

Tags: c#, .net, regex, testing

I'm implementing some integration tests and there is an entity with certain attributes that must be respected. The entity is the following:

```
[Table("ManualClassifiers")] 
public class ManualClassifier : Classifier
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z]+?)([-\s'][a-zA-Z]+)*?")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z]+?)([-\s'][a-zA-Z]+)*?")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password hash field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "passwordHash")]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password salt field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "passwordSalt")]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to validate the first regular expression, my test is always passing (even when my input is a white space, and hence, should fail or throw some error). This is the test:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public async Task Insert_ManualClassifier_With_Empty_Field_Fails()
    {
        using var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection) // Set the connection explicitly, so it won't be closed automatically by EF
            .Options;

        // Create the dabase schema
        // MigrateAsync if using Migrations
        using (var context = new DataContext(options))
        {
            await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
        } // The connection is not closed, so the database still exists

        using (var context = new DataContext(options))
        {
            var user = new ManualClassifier()
            {
                FirstName = "   ", //this is where it should not match the regular expression and fail
                LastName = "Last",
                Email = "example@gmail.com",
                Username = "firstlast123"
            };

            IRepositoryService repoService = new RepositoryService(context, NullLogger<RepositoryService>.Instance);

            string passwordHash = "pwhash";
            string passwordSalt = "pwsalt";

            int userID = await repoService.CreateUser(user, passwordHash, passwordSalt);
        }
    }
```

This is the repository method I'm invoking:

```
public async Task<int> CreateUser(ManualClassifier user, string passwordHash, string passwordSalt)
    {
        //TO DO: CREATE UPPER LAYER IN REPO PROJECT TO MAP RESULTS
        if (_context.ManualClassifiers.Any(u => u.Username == user.Username))
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"User with email {user.Username} already exists");
            throw new UsernameAlreadyExistsException(user.Username);
        }

        if (_context.ManualClassifiers.Any(u => u.Email == user.Email))
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"User with email {user.Email} already exists");
            throw new EmailAlreadyExistsException(user.Email);
        }

        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
        user.Email = user.Email.ToLower();

        _logger.LogDebug("New user created successfully");
        await _context.ManualClassifiers.AddAsync(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return user.Id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression validation for `FirstName` and `LastName` are missed end string anchor `$`. You should add the `$` anchor to the regex validation for these 2 fields.

```
[Table("ManualClassifiers")] 
public class ManualClassifier : Classifier
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z]+?)([-\s'][a-zA-Z]+)*?$")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z]+?)([-\s'][a-zA-Z]+)*?$")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password hash field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "passwordHash")]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password salt field is mandatory")]
    [Column(name: "passwordSalt")]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had already tried that solution and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are other validators worked, for example Required validator of `FirstName`?  Is there error if you set `FirstName` to be `null`?

Comment: When I use null, the entity framework throws the error of "NOT NULL constraint failed", which makes sense. But still, the regex data annotation is not working, which is strange.

Comment: I think the error `"NOT NULL constraint failed"` is not triggered by Required annotation of your entity. To validate object using data annotation outside of a UI framework, like ASP.NET MVC, your object should implement  IValidatableObject interface, then manually validate object using Validator. You should check these 2 link: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx https://garywoodfine.com/data-entity-validation-efcore/